# In Protractor using Javascript, can we use try/catch block for writing Test Validations?

Tags: protractor, jasmine-node

Through many blogs, i found that error handling can be handled through promises in protractor.In page object model the promises can be implemented in page file. 
would like to know , in Spec file where we write the Test validations code, will try/catch work in js file?

can some one please share the sample try/catch code in spec file of protractor.?
sample code:

```
it("try catch",function() {
  try {
    // calling page object methods
    homepage.clickingPosseLink()
    homepage.entercredintal(browser.params.username, browser.params.password);
    var number=homepage.textvalidation();
    //sometimes number will be blank from UI---- to handle this scenario i need try catch code
    if(number>200){
      //functionality code
    }
  }catch(err){
    console.log('Number retrieved from UI is blank');
  }
})
```

if number is blank,it should throw a exception message.But no action is happening because it is written in if loop.
expected is if any exception occur, it should catch and print the user defined message.
**Mentioned above is sample code. Main part is if exceptions occurs how to handle in it block using try catch block?**
Please suggest if the above approach is correct?If any other way can be implemented, please pinch in your valuable comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You even don't need to use `try-catch`.

I assume that `textvalidation` returns `number` type.

```
it("try catch",function(){
    homepage.clickingPosseLink();
    homepage.entercredintal(browser.params.username,browser.params.password);
    const number = homepage.textvalidation();
    const maxNumber = 200
    if(number > maxNumber){
        //some code
    } else if (number <= maxNumber){
        //some code
    } else {
       console.log(`Number retrieved from UI is "${number}"`);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi kacper, 
I have mentioned the code as one of the sample which lead to any exception. If any exception occurs. My main agenda is if any exception occurs in spec file[ignore promises which i will be handeling in page objects],any test validation which leads to exception, how can i able to achieve it using try catch? i there is any other way please suggest the same